# setting navigationcontroller bar to opaque moves detail scroll view down

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, mobile

I am using a search bar plus controller for a UITableview in my MasterController. When the view shows up, the navigationbar in the MasterController is black until the view fully loads (not sure why?). In order to fix this I set the `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false;` This fixed the issue I was having with the navigation bar being black initially, but now it looks like when I click a cell in the uitableview of the MasterController, the content in the DetailView that loads shifts down approximately the size of the search bar, but it's just blank space above the content that has been shifted... When I remove the translucent property in the MasterController the content in the DetailView is fine and not shifted...

SO my question is, what is shifting this content down and how can I stop the content from being shifted AND having an opaque navigation bar...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 7, by default your view controller's view extends under a translucent navigation bar when contained in a UINavigationController but not on an opaque one. You could set the `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` property of the view controller if you want it to extend under opaque nav bars too.

When you say your scroll view is shifted on your detail view controller it's probably because its y origin is not set to zero to offset for your view extending under a translucent nav bar, but because your nav bar is now opaque and your view is not extending under it the space is now visible.

One thing more view controllers will actually automatically add insets on scroll views they contain so that their contents are not obscured when the view controllers view extends under navigation bars. It is set by the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property which is by default is set to YES.

Comment: I went ahead and artificially moved them up even if it looks dumb in storyboard, it still works. This was all good information though. It helped me understand scrollviews a little better. Thanks.

Comment: It helped me. Thanks !